# Swift and Realm EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) when result is 0

Tags: swift, objective-c++, realm

I have a call in my code which looks innocuous enough:

`let index = allFilms.indexOfObject(film)`

It generally has no problems, but my application crashes at this line *when the value of index will be 0*, that is, when `film` is the first item in `allFilms`, with the error `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`.

This is a call to Realm, which internally uses the following Objective-C++ code to create the return value:

```
- (NSUInteger)indexOfObject:(RLMObject *)object 
  // [...]
  size_t object_ndx = object->_row.get_index();
  size_t result = _backingView.find_by_source_ndx(object_ndx);
  if (result == tightdb::not_found) {
    return NSNotFound;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Does anybody know what's happening here?

Just to make doubly clear, the index is not coming back as `NSNotFound`, it's coming back as `0`.

[edit] I'm wondering if Swift is doing some clever stuff where it's aware of how I'm casting this value further down the method. Here's the full method where you can see I'm doing some casting between `UInt` and `Int`.

```
func pageWithOffset(offset:Int, fromFilmWithIdentifier identifier:NSInteger)->UIViewController?{
    let allFilms = Film.objectsWithPredicate(FilmQueries.predicateForCurrentlyAvailable())

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == \(currentFilmIdentifier)")
    let film = Film.findById(currentFilmIdentifier)

    var index = allFilms.indexOfObject(film)

    if index == UInt(NSNotFound) { return nil }
    let resultIndex = Int(index) + offset;
    if index < 0 || index >= allFilms.count - 1{
        return nil
    }else{
        let film = allFilms[UInt(resultIndex)] as Film
        return pageForFilmWithIdentifier(film.id)
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post the stack trace from when the crash happens? Could it be a threading issue ?

Comment: This is all on the main thread, and I'm not passing objects between threads at any point (in fact `allFilms` is freshly loaded from the database within the body of the crashing method).

Comment: Here's the stack trace though https://gist.github.com/michaelforrest/dfbc3ff70acf49f2d488

Comment: I think it's something to do with Swift knowing that later in the method it will have to operate on the index as an Int and then cast it back to a UInt or something. I have managed to achieve my goal by taking a slightly different tack with the method body.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from when indexOfObject returns NSNotFound. You should check for `index == NSNotFound`, and if it is, then do not access the array.

Comment: It's not returning NSNotFound, it's returning 0.

Comment: Ok, my bad, the error message looked exaclty like when you trying to get an out-of-index element.

Answer (score 0):

This certainly looks like a Realm bug, though I can't reproduce it. Could you create a failing unit test in Realm that reproduces the issue? This is my (failed) attempt, which you can use as a jumping off point:

```
func testStackOverflow27982054() {
    let realm = realmWithTestPath()
    realm.transactionWithBlock {
        SwiftStringObject.createInRealm(realm, withObject: ["a"]); return
    }
    let allStrings = SwiftStringObject.objectsInRealm(realm, "stringCol == %@", "a")
    let index = allStrings.indexOfObject(allStrings[0] as SwiftStringObject)
    XCTAssertEqual(index, UInt(0))
}
```

Comment: I will have a go! I'll try and get a PR to you on GitHub next week.

Comment: Whatever helps us reproduce the issue! Either inline code sample or PR would be appreciated. Bonus points if you can fit it in a tweet ;)

Comment: Hi Michael, did you manage to find a reproducible case of this issue? We'd love to know if there's a bug on our side and if so, exactly how it manifests itself. Thanks!